# apache poi Picture resize() method no effect in linux?

Tags: java, linux, apache-poi

```
 draw.createPicture(anchor, book.addPicture(b, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG)).resize();
```

This resize() method seems not work exactly in linux, but in windows it works fine.
Is this a bug?
Also I have another question, how can I change the image size while not using the resize() method?
It seems Class HSSFClientAnchor can not change the image size also.